# Solver for the true auto-covariance function in AR(p)

Tags: r, time-series, autocorrelation, autoregressive, spectral-analysis

Suppose I have the following $AR(p)$ model.

$$X_t = \sum_{i=1}^{p} \phi_i X_{t-i} + \epsilon_t\,, $$

where $\epsilon_t$ has mean 0 variance $\sigma^2$. I am in the situation where the $\phi$s are known and my goal is to obtain the **true** auto-covariance
$$
\gamma(k) =  \text{Cov}(X_1, X_{1+k})\,.
$$
(I am not interested in estimating $\gamma(k)$). The spectral density at $0$ for AR$(p)$ model is
$$
f(0) = \sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} \gamma(k) = \dfrac{\sigma^2}{(1 - \sum_{i=1}^{p} \phi_i)^2}\,
$$
which is available in closed-form to me, since all of $\sigma^2$ and $\phi_i$ are known to me. Now, by the Yule-Walker equations, for $k = 1, \dots, p$
$$
\gamma(k) = \sum_{i=1}^{p} \phi_i \gamma(k-i)
$$
and $\gamma(0) = \sum_{i=1}^{p} \phi_i \gamma(k-i) + \sigma^2$.

Thus obtaining the true $\gamma(k)$ for $k = 0, \dots, p$ will require solving the above system of equations. I have two questions:

1. Is there an off-the-shelf R/Python/Matlab function available that outputs $\gamma(k)$ if I give it $\phi_i$ and $\sigma^2$?
2. What are the higher lag covariances: $\gamma(k)$ for $k > p$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### You can use `ARMA.autocov` in the `ts.extend` package

The [`ts.extend` package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ts.extend/ts.extend.pdf)  contains a number of functions that compute theoretical aspects of stationary  ARMA models, including the auto-correlation and auto-covariance functions, the auto-covariance matrix, and the standard probability functions for the stationary Gaussian ARMA model (i.e., density, distribution, and random-generation function).  The `ARMA.autocov` function takes an auto-regression vector `ar` and a moving-average vector `ma` (so long as the AR polynomial is for a stationary model) and gives the auto-correlation or auto-covariance function up to any specified length `n`.  (This function extends a similar function in the `stats` package, which lets you get the auto-correlation, but not the auto-covariance.$^\dagger$)  This can be implemented using the following syntax.

```
#Set the parameters
AR    <- c(0.8, -0.4, 0.2, 0.1)
sigma <- 5

#Compute auto-covariance function up to length n
AUTOCOV <- (sigma^2)*ts.extend::ARMA.autocov(n = 10, ar = AR)

#Plot the auto-correlation function
barplot(AUTOCOV, 
        main = 'Autocovariance Function\n(for an AR(4) model)',
        ylab = 'Autocovariance')
```

Note here that the parameter $\sigma$ is not part of the `ARMA.autocov` function, but it affects the auto-covariance by using multiplication by $\sigma^2$.

[image]

---

$^\dagger$ The function `stats::ARMAacf` computes the auto-*correlation* function, but there does not appear to be any function in the `stats` package to compute the auto-*covariance function*, which is quite annoying.  If you can separately compute the variance of the time-series values (i.e., the first element of the auto-covariance function) then you can multiply the auto-correlation function to get the auto-covariance function, but the `stats` package does not appear to give you a way to do this.